# Efficiently split pandas DataFrame by delimiters

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like

```
{
  "type": {
    "1590160049809": "boot",
    "1590160054895": "pick",
    "1590160057156": "pick",
    "1590160718705": "stop",
    "1590160772315": "boot",
    "1590160777015": "pick",
    "1590160785481": "pick"
  },
  "boot time": {
    "1590160049809": "1590160049.809339046",
    "1590160054895": null,
    "1590160057156": null,
    "1590160718705": null,
    "1590160772315": "1590160772.315527916",
    "1590160777015": null,
    "1590160785481": null
  },
  "capture time": {
    "1590160049809": null,
    "1590160054895": "1590160054.895216",
    "1590160057156": "1590160057.156712",
    "1590160718705": null,
    "1590160772315": null,
    "1590160777015": "1590160777.015709",
    "1590160785481": "1590160785.481504"
  },
  "end run time": {
    "1590160049809": null,
    "1590160054895": null,
    "1590160057156": null,
    "1590160718705": "1590160718.705250978",
    "1590160772315": null,
    "1590160777015": null,
    "1590160785481": null
  }
}
```

A section begins with a `boot` and may or may not end with an `end` if there's no `end` then I should choose the last `pick` in the series.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the time for each section. So something like `totalTime = end.timestamp - boot.timestamp` or if `end` wasn't there `pick.timestamp - boot.timestamp`

What I'm thinking is

1. find all the boot rows
2. take the range `df[boot[n]:boot[n+1]]`
3. choose the second from the last element for the end
4. calculate

```
boots = df[df["type"] == "boot"]
for i, boot in enumerate(boots, start=1):
    section = df[boots.iloc[0].name:boots.iloc[1].name][:-1]
    print(section.iloc[-1].name - section.iloc[0].name)
```

This gives me what I want but feels like I'm doing a lot of extra work. Also it would be nice to have the DataFrame split into chunks of `boot, pick, ..., pick, [end]`  I've only come across splitting on columns easily but haven't seen rows.

Is there a way of doing this with pandas?

Comment: it would really help the community if, you can provide a reproducible dataframe in question, It makes it so much more easier to try working on the solution

Comment: Adding to @SirajS. please add the desired output. Should just take 5 minutes and you will get  a better answer more quickly.

Comment: @SirajS. Does the edit help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating two extra columns, one for identifying each section, the other is the index which are the timestamps.

```
df['section'] = df['boot time'].ffill()
df['times'] = df.index
```

To get the boot time, we need to groupby each section and select the first row. Similarly for the end time / last capture time we groupby each section and select the last row.

```
boots = df.groupby('section')['times'].first()
ends = df.groupby('section')['times'].last()
```

Similarly to your approach of computing the totalTime:

```
totalTime = list(ends.astype(float) - boots.astype(float))
```

Output: `[668896.0, 13166.0]`